# Can you Moq a Where Claus when using Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

Hi is it possible to moq something like this. I'm using the MVC pattern and I'm testing my Controller Layer. I have already tested the method getListForId in my Service layer so I can trust that it will return the correct value.

```
public List<object> getListForID(int id)
```

And I use it like this

```
if(true)
{
    getListForID(1).Where(a => a.Id == objectB.Id)
}
else
{
    getListForID(1)
}
```

The code testing each path would be the same even tho there is a where in the true path.

Is it possible to verify that the method was called with the where clause ?
And is there any value in doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The `where` statement will give you a partial list of whatever `getListForID` returned.

Comment: I would say that there is no point. You should test result, not the way something is implemented.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way of checking if the where is called. I'll edit my question to provide a clearer example

Comment: I suppose I could Moq an IList and then Verify that Where is called once. @PiotrAuguscik I am using the MVC pattern I have already tested the method getListId() I am testing the controller so I'm more interested in the flow of the code rather than the values returned. I'll add that detail to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test a behavior, not the implementation. If you already have tested the service layer, then for your controller tests you should mock the service layer, and make `getById` return a list of objects with possible values, then test that this list was filtered correctly:

(pseudo code follows)

```
// arrange
var serviceOutput = new List<MyEntity>
{
   new MyEntity{Id = 1},
   new MyEntity{Id = 2}
}
var mockService = new Mock<IMyService>();
mockService.Setup(s=>s.GetById(1)).Returns(serviceOutput);

var lookupObject = new MyEntity{Id = 1};

var testController = new MyController(mockService.Object);

// act
var result = controller.FindSimilar(lookupObject);

// assert
result.Should().Have.Count().EqualTo(1);
result[0].Should().Be.SameInstanceAs(serviceOutput[0]);
```